# Automate `--ours` and `--theirs` during `git rebase`

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I have a 500-commit long rebase for which I must specify the same files to favor via `github checkout --ours file.py` and `--theirs` for each commit; is there a way to automate this by telling [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) to apply this preference for all further conflicts?

Comment: I'll note that it's rare that just taking ours/theirs is right during rebase. It's not completely impossible, just rare—and if you find yourself in one of those cases, that *probably* means that `git rebase` is the wrong tool anyway.

Comment: @torek My PR was based on one branch, but library rebased into another, and now I must merge into that one instead -- yes, I'm certain `--ours` and `--theirs` always remains same in this case. If there's a better approach, I could open a question.

Comment: The upstream doing their own rebase *is* a candidate for one of those rare cases. It sounds like you've hit one. This sort of thing is of course why other people shouldn't rebase public code, if possible: it makes for big headaches for folks like *you*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a thoughtless process, then feel free to write a script... something like:

```
git rebase blahblahblah
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    # rebase stopped for whatever reason
    while true; do
        git checkout --ours blahblah
        # more commands to specify what should be attempted with each file
        git add . # add all files.... perhaps something a little mlre specific would help
        # let's try again
        GIT_EDITOR=/bin/true git rebase --continue
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            break # we are done
        fi
    done
fi
```

Comment: I decided to give up after it started throwing unsolvable internal errors but I'll trust this works